# Getting SQL deadlock when inserting and deleting at the same time

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, clustered-index

Currently I get occasional deadlocks in the MSSQL database of my .NET application. I am using stored procedures to add data to a table "DATA_CONT". Additionally there is a periodic task to delete old data from this table. Sometimes when inserting and deleting procedure perform at the same time, I get a deadlock.

The table DATA_CONT owns one clustered index containing the Foreign Key CID (uniqueidentifier) and the ResultDate (datetime2(3)).

This is the deadlock xml graph of MS SQL:

```xml
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process6137528c8" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="process6137528c8" taskpriority="5" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 7:72057594046185472 (0d3d2e12b103)" waittime="1637" ownerId="9357686" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2018-11-12T11:20:55.167" XDES="0x61e4703b0" lockMode="RangeS-U" schedulerid="7" kpid="14644" status="suspended" spid="53" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="-5" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-11-12T11:20:55.167" lastbatchcompleted="2018-11-12T11:20:55.167" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.167" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="FE-Z13YL" hostpid="24056" loginname="DE\afr3fe" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="9357686" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="1800" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="MyDatabase.dbo.Proc_DeleteDataCont" line="12" stmtstart="708" stmtend="954" sqlhandle="0x03000700f2a6e25b72b58a0092a9000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
Delete From
        [DATA_CONT]
    WHERE
        CID = @p_CID AND
        (@p_DeleteOlderThan IS NULL OR ResultDate &lt; @p_DeleteOlderThan    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 7 Object Id = 1541580530]   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process658113468" taskpriority="0" logused="592" waitresource="KEY: 7:72057594046185472 (ae5185f64403)" waittime="1711" ownerId="9357687" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2018-11-12T11:20:55.170" XDES="0x65cd77000" lockMode="RangeI-N" schedulerid="6" kpid="21008" status="suspended" spid="52" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-11-12T11:20:55.170" lastbatchcompleted="2018-11-12T11:20:55.170" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.170" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="FE-Z13YL" hostpid="24056" loginname="DE\afr3fe" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="9357687" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="MyDatabase.dbo.Proc_AddDataCont" line="8" stmtstart="266" stmtend="598" sqlhandle="0x030007005654c5593a84070188a9000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
INSERT INTO [DATA_CONT] SELECT CID, Value, LocationData, ResultDate, GETUTCDATE() FROM @p_DataContLis    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 7 Object Id = 1506104406]   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <keylock hobtid="72057594046185472" dbid="7" objectname="MyDatabase.dbo.DATA_CONT" indexname="IX_DATA_CONT" id="lock620b19a80" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594046185472">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process658113468" mode="X" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process6137528c8" mode="RangeS-U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
  <keylock hobtid="72057594046185472" dbid="7" objectname="MyDatabase.dbo.DATA_CONT" indexname="IX_DATA_CONT" id="lock620b19800" mode="RangeS-U" associatedObjectId="72057594046185472">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process6137528c8" mode="RangeS-U" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process658113468" mode="RangeI-N" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

For me it seems that both locks are being escalated. How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: `@p_DeleteOlderThan IS NULL` don't use a parameter if you don't want it. The server will cache an execution plan the *first* time a query gets executed. This can result in inefficient execution plans. An *in*efficient execution plan ends up locking more rows for far longer. That can easily lead to deadlocks

Comment: Assuming the "delete old data" procedure isn't critical, consider setting `DEADLOCK_PRIORITY` to `LOW`, deleting in small batches, assigning a liberal retry policy and ignoring deadlocks from this process altogether, checking only if the deletes happen fast enough to keep the table in line. Aside from all other things you might do to reduce/eliminate deadlocks, it often isn't possible or profitable to completely get rid of them when ignoring them will do. (Obviously, this isn't true of all deadlocks because not everything can be retried -- but cleanup can.)

Comment: As Jeroen said, I set `DEADLOCK_PRIORITY` of delete procedure to `LOW`. So if there is a deadlock again, the less important task will be canceled. 
The hint of Panagiotis is good, I have to try to avoid the optional filter parameter. For testing I removed this parameter, but I still get deadlocks.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that it is not critical your delete process to skip some rows (from time to time). My idea is to skip locked rows when deleting using "READPAST" hint like that:

```
Delete From
    [DATA_CONT] WITH (READPAST)
WHERE
    CID = @p_CID AND
    (@p_DeleteOlderThan IS NULL OR ResultDate &lt; @p_DeleteOlderThan
```

Comment: "You can only specify the READPAST lock in the READ COMMITTED or REPEATABLE READ isolation levels." This seems not to work in the used isolation level, but thanks for that solution!

Comment: Sorry, i didn't saw isolation level.
Can you prevent "inserting" to fire together with "deleting". 
I suggest waiting for some result after "deleting", and then fire the "insert".